# Mocking Bigquery for integration test

Tags: go, testing, integration-testing

I'm using https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-go to interact with GCP Bigquery to fetch some data.

I want to write some tests for my code. for the unit testing, it's easy because I can mock my repository ( data layer) and return what I expected for.

I'm looking for writing an integration test,  if it was just basic HTTP I could write a httptest server and return some dummy ( fake) data. but this library is using gRPC to communicate with GCP Bigquery.

I'm wondering how I can write an integration test for GCP Bigquery in Golang.

let's keep it in the simplest way and just provide the integration part for `Query a table in a dataset and read data`.

Comment: Haven't evaluated or used this,  but perhaps you could consider this? https://github.com/goccy/bigquery-emulator

Comment: @EmilePels I'm looking for a solution without adding more dependency to my project if it's possible. something like general httptest mocking that usually we do to mock external data sources.

Comment: Can you include more details about what your idea integration test looks like? Are you looking for a fake BigQuery endpoint you can point your test towards?

Comment: @kingkupps Thank you for your attention, let's suppose I want to query a table and read data from a table in a dataset.

Answer (score 4):

You can run dependency locally. Read :
[Docker container for Google BigQuery](https://hub.docker.com/r/openbridge/ob_google-bigquery)

You can write script for running tests and dependencies(BigQuery) in docker container

If you dont want to run test using docker you can use [bigquery-emulator](https://github.com/goccy/bigquery-emulator)

Or just mock it
Send your repository(data layer) as interface to your http server
And then you run test use mock

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I knew the first two options, could you please provide details for the third option you suggested?

Comment: Create Mock for your repo layer and use it when  you start your http server.

Comment: it's not the way to do the integrational test, we expected to act with mocked external part not a mocking repository layer.

Comment: Then you have to use one of two previous option

Comment: I knew those solutions, I'm looking for other solutions and I believe there are, something like https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-go-testing/bigquery/bqiface and more. btw Thank you for your attention.